# Is the modulo operation cheaper in unchecked arithmetic?

Tags: gas, math, solidity-0.8.x, modulo

The docs on [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html) mention that overflows are now checked by default:

> Arithmetic operations revert on underflow and overflow. You can use [unchecked { ... }](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic) to use the previous wrapping behaviour.

But it is unclear whether the modulo operation (%) classifies as an arithmetic operation. As per the docs:

> It is not possible to disable the check for division by zero or **modulo by zero** using the unchecked block.

So my guess is that modulo shouldn't be faster in unchecked arithmetic. Is that correct?

Comment: Note to my future self: open a discussion in the [Solidity forum](https://forum.soliditylang.org/) to suggest making the default arithmetic checks cheaper than the `unchecked` approach. The current state of affairs motivates devs to write implementations that are more complex than what they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, modulo is cheaper in unchecked arithmetic! Take the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Modulos {
    function foo(uint256 x, uint256 y) external view returns (uint256 result, uint256 gasUsed) {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        result = x % y;
        gasUsed = startGas - gasleft();
    }
    
    function bar(uint256 x, uint256 y) external view returns (uint256 result, uint256 gasUsed) {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        unchecked {
            result = x % y;
            gasUsed = startGas - gasleft();
        }
    }
   
}
```

Passing 11 and 3 as `x` and `y`, respectively, yields the following gas costs:

- 72 gas for `foo`
- 23 gas for `bar`

You can test for yourself on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org). I am not sure why this is the case - as per my explanation in the question body, I was expecting no difference in gas costs.

**Side-node**: You can also work with the assembly [mod](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/yul.html#evm-dialect) operation:

```
contract Modulos {
    function baz(uint256 x, uint256 y) external view returns (uint256 result, uint256 gasUsed) {
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        assembly {
            result := mod(x, y)
        }
        gasUsed = startGas - gasleft();
    }
}
```

This costs as much as the unchecked arithmetic (23 gas).